# Is it possible to call java main event loop?

Tags: java, swing, java-native-interface

I could not find any answer related to this question.   I wonder if it is possible.  Here is my problem.

I have a core processing application written in Fortran.  The application needs a new UI.   The Fortran code has its own main loop.   It communicates
with the UI through a interface routine.   This routine calls the main event loop of
whatever UI library that its used, for example the current UI is Motif.   So it calls
the Motif main event loop.   I would like to replace Motif with Java swing.   I could not find thing on Java main event loop.   My questions are
1)  Is it possible to call Java main loop directly ?
2)  I know it possible for Java to call another language.  How can another language call a Java routines ?

-------------- Additional comments

It looks like it might not be possible to do this, at least not the way I envision it.     Here is an algorithm that I try to use

do loop until terminate
    do some internal processing
  1 check ui event queue
   if queue has event
  2    call ui event dispatcher for all UI events
end loop

what I like to know, is there any kind of routine to replace #1 and #2.   I was hoping Java has something like  EventQueue.hasEvent ();
    EventQueue.dispatchEvent (event);

From the comments so far, it does not look like there is such a thing.

Comment: It looks like it may not be possible to do this.  At least not the way I envision it.   Here is algorithm of the main loop I that try to use

Comment: @tadpole: why do you want to see if there are events in the queue? That part is indeed not really possible in Java, but I don't understand why you think you need it.

Comment: If there is no event in the queue, there is no need to dispatch the event.   What is there to dispatch ?   This is normal approach to any UI main event loop.

Comment: If you look at other UI libraries like Motif, Qt, tcl, etc ...,, that is how UI events are processed.  Whether the event processing is exposed for the users is depending the language philosophy.  I guess Java does not believe in this.  For my case, I cannot change the Fortran code, I can only change the interface to another language.

Comment: @tadpole the loop is handled by an additional thread, this thread takes care of 1 and 2. If your processing should happen in the same thread you can post calls to your code with SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait

Comment: Perhaps I am complicating things by keeping the current processing sequence.  Instead of having fortran calls java code, I should have java calls fortran code.  It will be days or even weeks before I can get thing working.  Til then thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1. [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and [`invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
2. JNI [can be used](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/intro.html#1811) to embed a JVM in a native application and communicate with it via a linked library. But in your scenario, it would probably best to have the UI run as a separate process and communicat with the core application via sockets.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot call the GUI main event loop directly; however, you can submit items to the main event loop to eventually be ran on its Thread.

The main event loop does a lot of things inside the GUI, some of those things are scheduling the graphics to be drawn, accepting input, etc.  It's a design choice, and Java went with a multi-threading model where the non-GUI code doesn't run in the GUI event loop.  The reasoning behind it is likely due to the GUI loop possibly being paused or corrupted causing GUI performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can refashion your application to run as a Java app, and invoke your Fortran stuff via JNI. Then within your Java app you can get the system [event queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) by `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue()`, and call its `peekEvent` and `postEvent`.

Comment: Thank you.  So far this seems to be most relevant to what I am trying to do.   Although I am not sure of the details, but this is a start. From the limited dealing with JNI, I have seen Java calls other languages, but not other way around.

Comment: Yes, JNI by definition goes one way (from @oyo's link): "... so the JVM can locate and invoke native methods". The other way would be "FNI" or something like that :)

Comment: Swig will also help with this. I have an enterprise application that does exactly this. It's a Java application that calls Fortran code to run numerical methods that perform simulations. Swig just uses JNI, so you could use JNI directly, but I find Swig speeds up development time. I also have C++ middleware between Java and Fortran because there are some C++/C parts of the simulation code. See https://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html

I then use CMake to build this part of the application as it has good Swig support.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Java Native Interface](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) (question 2 ;))